# Зависимость высоты изображения от текста в соседнем блоке (CSS)

Tags: css, flexbox, hidden, overflow

Сверстал два контейнера внутри родительского с выравниванием flex. В левом изображение, в правом - текст из 4 строк. На большом экране строк становится 3, а на маленьком - 5 и более. Мне нужно, чтобы изображение увеличивалось по высоте за счет показа скрытой части, выравниваясь по высоте текстового блока, и чтобы ширина оставалась неизменной.
Чтобы на больших экранах сохранять минимум 3 строки - добавил max-width текстовому блоку.
Исходное изображение 400х300, ширина фиксированная, высота для трех строк - 150px. Нужно, чтобы при появлении четвертой строки высота добавлялась. 
Подозреваю, что рыть надо где-то в overflow: hidden; или align-items: stretch; Но уложить пока в голове не могу. 
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3>Заголовок
        </h3>
        <div class="text_1">        
        </div>
        <div class="text_2">
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: left;
}

.photo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

.text {
  max-width: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.photo {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

или

```
.photo {
    background-image:url('%url to your image%');
}
```

`align-items` тут не поможет.

Comment: перефразируй вопрос свой лаконично.

Comment: и приведи рабочий пример, тот который ты построил: с изображением, строками. Тебе тут не экстрасенсы с канала ТНТ сидят.

Comment: Vladimir Rodichev, это ты мне? Мне тут нечего добавить. И хоть я и не экстрасенс, но как-то смог же представить ситуацию =)

Comment: нет, не тебе. Нет конкретного кода (попытки). Прислуживай дальше. Что тут добавить.

Comment: Не получается с хидден. В том плане, что он не привязан к высоте соседнего блока. Как привести другой код - не знаю. У меня просто в одном месте стоит фото, в другом текст. Если это сложно представить - значит, наверное, это не ваше. Ну или у меня задача какая-то гиперстрашная, что всех в тупик поставила. А вообще, конечно, когда паренек лет на 19 на вид каждому встречному тыкает и строит мегагуру - это смешно :-)

Comment: VladimirRodichev, тебя обидел кто-то, что ли?

danalex, у меня получается. Может, действительно стоит переформулировать задачу?